# Pandas read_sql_query with WHERE condition on VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas, read-sql

I am trying to pull data from a certain database, the database is huge so I would like to query it before getting the data into python. I want to query on a specific column [Type] that I know is type varchar(50). As a test  tried to query on an integer column successfully:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Prices where Price = 1', conn)
```

However when I try and do the same with the varchar column it tells me the column name is invalid.

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Prices where Type = Daily', conn)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `where Type = Daily` is comparing the Type column with the Daily column. Strings in SQL need to be quoted, just like any other language. Use `where Type = 'Daily'`

Comment: Im still getting an invalid column name with this :(

Comment: What is the *actual* error, what did you actually try? This isn't a matter of opinion. If you don't use quotes, it's not a string. Did you use the *correct* quotes? Did you use `"SELECT * FROM Prices where Type = 'Daily'"` ? If not you'd have to escape the single quotes in the Python string `'SELECT * FROM Prices where Type = \'Daily\''`

Comment: Try the query first with any client tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio, which is actually a cross-platform SQL Server Data Studio. Once you have a valid query *then* convert it into a Python string

Answer (score 0):

I incurred to the same problem, I solved using a combination of strings (especially the docstring). You should try something like:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM "Prices" where "Type" = 'Daily'
''', conn)
```

The line brake is important! I think that for the sake of sql syntax, the quote on the value must be of this type: ' and not ".